# Vue 3 Vuelidate not working with component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

I am using vue 3 / typescript . I have 2 forms one is for patient registration and other is for patient visits both forms required validation on some fields. I am using vuelidate to validate both forms. I am have applied validation on both forms patient and visit . patient form is a component and i injected it inside the visit page .The problem is when i add patient component inside visit page vailidation on visit page get fails. but then i comment out the patient compoment on visit page it works fine. both forms are independent form each other.

**Here is the patient registration component**

```
 <template>
        <Dialog
            id="previewReceiptDailog"
            v-model:visible="productDialog"
            :style="{ width: '60vw' }"
            position="top"
            class="p-fluid"
            :modal="true"
            :closable="true"
            @hide="closeDialog"
        >
            <template #header>
                <h6 class="p-dialog-titlebar p-dialog-titlebar-icon">
                    <i class="pi pi-plus-circle"></i> {{ dialogTitle }}
                </h6>
            </template>
    
            <div class="p-grid">
                <div class="p-col-6">
                    <div class="p-field">
                        <label
                            for="firstName"
                            :class="{
                                'p-error': v$.firstName.$invalid && submitted
                            }"
                            >First Name</label
                        >
                        <InputText
                            id="firstName"
                            v-model="v$.firstName.$model"
                            :class="{
                                'p-invalid': v$.firstName.$invalid && submitted
                            }"
                        />
                        <small
                            v-if="
                                (v$.firstName.$invalid && submitted) ||
                                    v$.firstName.$pending.$response
                            "
                            class="p-error"
                            >{{
                                v$.firstName.required.$message.replace(
                                    "Value",
                                    "First Name"
                                )
                            }}</small
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
              
            </div>
    
            <template #footer>
                <Button
                    type="button"
                    label="Save"
                    icon="pi pi-check-circle"
                    class="p-button-primary pull-left"
                    @click.prevent="saveItem(!v$.$invalid)"
                />
            </template>
        </Dialog>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
    import { reactive } from "vue";
    import { required } from "@vuelidate/validators";
    import useVuelidate from "@vuelidate/core";
   
    
    @Options({
        props: {
            PatientRegistration: Object
        },
        watch: {
            PatientRegistration(obj) {
                this.openDialog();
                this.dialogTitle = obj.dialogTitle;
                this.productDialog = obj.status;
    
                if (obj.patientID != 0) {
                    this.loadPatient(obj.patientID);
                }
            }
        },
        emits: ["updatePatientStatus"]
    })
    export default class PatientDialog extends Vue {
   
        private submitted = false;
        private state = reactive({
            firstName: "",
          
        });
    
       
    
        private validationRules = {
            firstName: {
                required
            },
           
        };
    
        private v$ = useVuelidate(this.validationRules, this.state);
    
        //DEFAULT METHOD OF TYPE SCRIPT
        //CALLING WHENEVER COMPONENT LOADS
        created() {
            this.toast = new Toaster();
            this.patientService = new PatientService();
        }
    
     
    
        saveItem(isFormValid) {
            this.submitted = true;
            if (isFormValid) {
               //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    
     
    }
    </script>
```

**Here is the visit page where i injeceted the component of patient**

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div class="app-container">
            <Dialog
                v-model:visible="productDialog"
                :style="{ width: '50vw' }"
                :maximizable="true"
                position="top"
                class="p-fluid"
            >
           
                <template #header>
                    <h5 class="p-dialog-titlebar p-dialog-titlebar-icon">
                        {{ dialogTitle }}
                    </h5>
                </template>
                 <form @submit.prevent="saveVisitItem(!v1$.$invalid)">
               
                <div class="p-field">
                    <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                    <InputText
                        id="notes"
                         v-model="v1$.notes.$model"
                         :class="{
                            'p-invalid': v1$.notes.$invalid && submitted
                        }"
                    />
                    <small
                        v-if="
                            (v1$.notes.$invalid && submitted) ||
                                v1$.notes.$pending.$response
                        "
                        class="p-error"
                        >{{
                            v1$.notes.required.$message.replace(
                                "Value",
                                "Notes"
                            )
                        }}</small
                    >
                </div>
                 <Button
                        type="submit"
                        label="Save"
                        icon="pi pi-check"
                        class="p-button-primary"
                    />
                </form>
               
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    </section>

    <PatientDialog
        :PatientRegistration="{
            patientID: this.patientID,
            status: this.patientDialogStatus,
            dialogTitle: this.dialogTitle
        }"
        v-on:updatePatientStatus="updatePatientStatus"
    />

    
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import VisitService from "../../service/VisitService.js";
import { reactive } from "vue";
import useVuelidate from "@vuelidate/core";
import { required } from "@vuelidate/validators";
import PatientDialog from "../../components/PatientDialog.vue";
import AutoComplete from "primevue/autocomplete";

@Options({
    components: {
        PatientDialog,
        AutoComplete
    }
})
export default class EncounterVisit extends Vue {
   

    private validationRules = {
        notes: {
            required
        }
    };

    private visitFormState = reactive({
        notes: "",
    });

    private v1$ = useVuelidate(this.validationRules, this.visitFormState);
    


    //ADD OR UPDATE THE ITEM VIA HTTP
    saveVisitItem(isFormValid) {

        this.submitted = true;

        console.log(this.v1$);
        console.log(isFormValid);

       //this.submitted = false;
       
    }

}
</script>
```

The response i get from the console log is

```
$anyDirty: true
$clearExternalResults: ƒ $clearExternalResults()
$dirty: false
$error: false
$errors: []
$getResultsForChild: ƒ $getResultsForChild(key)
$invalid: true
$model: null
$path: "__root"
$pending: false
$reset: () => {…}
$silentErrors: (5) [Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy]
$touch: () => {…}
$validate: ƒ ()
notes: Proxy {$dirty: ComputedRefImpl, $path: 'notes', required: {…}, $touch: ƒ, $reset: ƒ, …}
_vuelidate_72: Proxy {$dirty: ComputedRefImpl, $path: '__root', $model: null, $touch: ƒ, $reset: ƒ, …}
[[Prototype]]: Object

false
```

Comment: Can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? The code that you posted is bulky, it could be be many times smaller, as long as it reproduces the problem.

Comment: see i have made it shorter

Comment: It's unclear from the code how EncounterVisit is related to it. Try to specify scope for both v instances, https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/advanced_usage.html#scope-property , this can help. The problem is that you use classes. Since they do some black magic inside, and Vuelidate is for pure composition, it's unknown to the wider public (myself included) what exactly happens internally.